# How to make the following plot

Tags: plotting, syntax

Consider the following dataset:

```
tab1 = Table[{i, i^2, 0.8*i^(3/2), i^4}, {i, 1, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Is it possible to make a plot similar to the one shown below (where there is $i$ instead of $p_{T}$)

Comment: You can also use Lukas Lang's ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]:(https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As recommended by kglr, **with version 12.0 and later**, use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) "PlotGrid"

```
tab1 = Table[{i, i^2, 0.8*i^(3/2), i^4}, {i, 1, 10, 1}];

tab2 = Transpose[tab1];

data = Transpose[{tab2[[1]], #}] & /@ Rest[tab2];

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {ListPlot[#, Frame -> True]} & /@ data,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
    {"i", "whatever"})]
```

[image]